# Loading FullCalendar Scheduler with LazyLoad

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm working in an environment where I have to load FullCalendar via LazyLoad from the web - I can't install it on a server.  I've written the script below, and I do see the calendar generated - however, it is simple day view without the resources.  It seems like maybe the Scheduler portion is not loading correctly?  I want it to look exactly like this sample:  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-standard-demo

Thanks for any help!

```
LazyLoad.js(['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.js'], function () {
    LazyLoad.js(['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'], function () {
      LazyLoad.js(['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'], function () {
        LazyLoad.js(['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/scheduler.min.js'], function () {
          $('#kn-scene_118').prepend('<div id="calendar"></div>');
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            groupByResource: true,
            resources: [
              { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
              { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' }
            ],
            events: [
              {
                title  : 'event1',
                start  : '2019-01-12T12:00:00',
                allDay : false,
                resourceId : 'a'
              }
            ]
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: further data: it seems the environment I'm running in already uses fullCalendar, although I haven't confirmed which version.  I would think I could then just load Scheduler, but then I get an error ""scheduler.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mixin' of undefined".